# CSS Text effect: text appears on screen for a second before the effect

Tags: jquery, css

Probably very simple but got me stumped.

I have an overlay menu and some navigation links inside it. What I'd like to do is a simple "slide up" text effect, wherein the text seems to "rise up" from the baseline. It's a commonly seen effect, and I have achieved it playing with line-height and a super simple animation.

The jQuery: basically, the idea is that when somebody clicks on the menu icon, the text appears AS it slides up.

**The problem: the effect "works", however, when I open the menu, the text actually appears for a split second BEFORE the effect kicks in.**

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li><span>Hello</span></li>
  <li><span>Dog</span></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li {
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 1;
}

.reveal {
  display: block;
  animation: reveal 1.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1) 0.5s; 
}

@keyframes reveal {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
   }
}
```

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('button').click(function () {

      //make overlay appear
      $('li span').addClass('reveal');  //adds the animation to the text
  });

});
```

This [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m4rbot/v7qvdu46/) will show you the effect I'm going for and the problem. Note: the code is super broken, I just need help with the effect itself.

I understand why it happens: I'm telling the browser to translate the text 100% AFTER it has already appeared on screen, without hiding it first. How do I hide the text until the animation kicks in?

Nothing I've tried has worked. I just want the text to be invisible UNTIL it slides up into view. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: i guess to start out with the initial animation at 0% you want to add that same setting to the span intially: li span{transform: translate(0, 100%);}

Comment: @Liquidchrome oy vey it works! I spent one hour just applying visibility:hidden, opacity:0, hide() to whatever element I could find and the answer was right under my nose. I'll give you the bounty if you repost this as the answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `animation-fill-mode: forwards` to maintain the end state of the animation. And then translate the starting state:

```
span{
    transform: translate(0, 100%);
}

.reveal { 
  display: block;
  animation: reveal 1.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1) 0.5s forwards;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To start out with the initial animation at 0% you want to add that same setting to the span intially: li span{transform: translate(0, 100%);}

Comment: Your advice was correct; however, the other poster added a crucial detail (forwards fill-mode) which thoroughly solves the problem. Thank you for your help anyway!